# If $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x^{2011})^{\frac{1}{2011}}}$, then number of solutions of the equation [CONT]

Tags: functions

> If $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x^{2011})^{\frac{1}{2011}}}$, then number of solutions of the equation $\underbrace{f\circ f\circ\dots\circ f}_{2013} (x)=\{-x\}$ is?

Upon compilation, I got

$$f\circ f\circ f(x)=x$$
$$f\circ f\circ f\circ f=f(x)$$ so ever fourth term ends up being $f(x)$

Since there are 2013 terms, all terms up to 2012 will end up being $f(x)$, so the final result will be $f\circ f(x)$

Now solving this with $-x$ is extremely difficult to do, which made think that I was actually supposed to end up with $f\circ f\circ f(x)=$, which would give me 2 solutions.

Did I solve this right?

Comment: Since 2013 is divisible by 3, shouldn't it be the number of solutions to $x = -x$

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan that would work (thanks for pointing it out), but why doesn’t the above approach work?

Comment: What do you mean with $\{-x\}$ in $RHS$ of the equation?

Comment: @FormulaWriter $\{\}$ denotes the fractional part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re correct till you get $$f\circ f\circ f\circ f =f(x) $$ Notice if we apply the operation of $f$ *three* times, we get $$f^7 (x) = f^4(x) = f(x) $$ Doing this again, $$f^{10}(x) =f^4 (x) =f(x) $$ Notice the pattern here. $f^n (x)=f(x)$ if $n=4+3k$ for $k\in\mathbb N$.

The greatest number less than $2013$ of the form $4+3k$ is $2011$, so $$f^{2011} (x) =f(x) \implies f^{2013} (x) =f^3( x )=x$$ Now you just need to solve $$x=\{-x\}$$ This yields $1$ solution : $$x=\frac 12$$ The solution $x=0$ Is excluded, because the domain of $f^{2013} (x)$ is $\mathbb R -\{0,1\} $.

Comment: So $x=0$ and what will be the other $x$?

Comment: @Aditya Check my edit.

Comment: Actually $\{-1\}=0$, so $x=1$ is not a solution. Moreover, $x=0$ must be excluded, since it is a zero of the denominator of $f^2$.

Comment: @FormulaWriter Removed $x=1$. But does $x=0$ being a zero of the denominator of $f^2$ really matter here?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking you can't compute $f^2(0)$, therefore $x=0$  cannot be plugged into the original equation, just as when you solve $\frac{x^2-x}{x}=0$.

Comment: @FormulaWriter But computing $f^2(0)$ is not an intermediate step here, one needs to compute the function $f^{2013} (x)$, and then plug in $x=0$.

Comment: If $x=1/2$, then x can also be $\frac 13, \frac 15$ etc

Comment: @Aditya No, for instance $$\{-\frac 13 \} = -\frac 13 - \lfloor -\frac 13 \rfloor = -\frac 13 -(-1) = \frac 23 \ne \frac 13$$

Comment: @Tavish The point is, when you state $f^3(x)=x$ you are implicitly assuming that $x \neq 0,1$, for otherwise you get a $0/0$ expression. The domain of the function $f^{2013}$ is indeed $\mathbb{R}-\{0, 1\}$. Anyway, except for this, the proof is good.

Comment: @FormulaWriter Actually, I see now that you’re right. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

By my calculations, I'm getting the following

$$f(x) = (1-x^{2011})^{-2011}$$

$$f(f(x)) = \left[1 - \left((1-x^{2011})^{-2011}\right)^{2011}\right]^{-2011}$$

$$f(f(x)) = \left[1-(1-x^{2011})\right]^{-2011} = x$$

So the above problem would become to solve

$$f(x) = x$$

$$\implies 1-x^{2011} = x^{2011}$$

$$\implies x^{2011}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Number of real solutions of this should be $1$

Comment: I am pretty confident that $f(f(f(x)))=x$ and not $f(f(x))$

Comment: I am sorry, someone edited my question and wrongly wrote the question. I have fixed it now